# How to create a loop with a pause that reverses when reaching the end react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently trying to create a mock draft app for fantasy sports. Stuck on trying to figure out how to loop through all of the teams, while pushing an object into each team array, then pausing when it is the user's turn. After the user picks his player (object) the loop continues until it reaches the end of the round (teams.length) at which point it should reverse and continue in descending order until it reaches the user again and then back until index = 0. and then repeat this several times.

what i have so far :

```
//draftAction.js

export const addPlayerToTeam = (j) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let myTeam = getState().draftPreferencesReducer.draftPos
  let player = getState().playersReducer.players
  let allTeams = getState().draftPreferencesReducer.teams
  if (j){ j = myTeam } 
  else {j = 0}
  for (let i = j, di=1; i < allTeams.length; i+= di) {
    if (i !== myTeam-1){
    setTimeout(function(x) { return function() {
      return dispatch ({
        type: ADD_TO_TEAM,
        player: player[x],
        team: x,
      })
      }; }(i), 1000*i);
    }
    else { return }
  }
}


export const addPlayerToMyTeam = (player, team) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  let myTeam = getState().draftPreferencesReducer.draftPos
  let allTeams = getState().draftPreferencesReducer.teams
  allTeams[myTeam-1].push(player)
  return dispatch ({
    type: ADD_TO_MY_TEAM,
    player,
    playersUsed: playersDrafted
  })
}
```

the main function is addPlayerToTeam. teams is a multi-dimensional array with several empty arrays inside (the user inputs how many teams he'd like there to be). Our user's team is spliced and thrown into the teams array. draftPos (used here as myTeam) is the index where the user's team is placed.
essentially I'm trying to loop through myTeams then pause when the index == draftPos then continue until we reach myTeams.length and then reverse back to draftPos, pause again, then continue til index = 0. Any help is extremely appreciated.